# Simple Bash OS heelp

Tags: bash, operating-system

I am trying to write a bare-bones OS. When I say bare-bones I mean just system essentials: bash, mount, cd, ls, etc..

Where is a good place to start?

I've looked all over the internet but found nothing :(

Comment: Get Andrew Tanenbaum's book *[ Operating Systems: Design and Implementation](http://vig.prenhall.com/catalog/academic/product/0,1144,0131429388,00.html)*, which describes [MINIX](http://www.minix3.org/).

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page might a good place to start as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Lightweight Linux Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution) from Wikipedia.

[BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net) is another starting point.

Comment: the first link is usefull, but doesn't answer question well. the second is perfect, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own distro with LFS : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

You can control what you include or not.

Comment: If i could accept two I would accept this too... but you posted last... still +1